# What does QTest::currentTestFailed() return for the init and cleanup TestCase functions?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qtestlib, qttest

Currently using QT 4.8 and according to the document the QTest::currentTestFailed() "Returns true if the current test function failed, otherwise false." I am not sure if this means the value will give the failed/succeeded result of the init function, or the unit test called before it.

Answer (score 0):

The `currentTestFailed()` function returns the result of the unit test the `init` function is initializing for. The same goes for the cleanup.